# Android UnifiedNativeAds causing Memory leaks

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have a problem with properly destroying Unified Native Ads in a RecyclerView.
I am loading Ads through an AdManager class which holds references of the loaded Ads. I also have a destroy() method in my AdManager class which I call to destroy all referenced Ads for the calling RecyclerView.
In my RecyclerView Adapter I also have a destroy() method where I call the destroy() method of the AdManager.
The destroy() method from my Adapter is called in the onDestroyView() method of the Fragment containing the RecyclerView. The Fragment lies within a Activity which has a parent activity.
When I go back to the parent activity the leak occurs.

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Local variable in native code
│
├─ Bu instance
│    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader↓ is not leaking)
│    Thread name: 'CleanupReference'
│    ↓ Bu.contextClassLoader
├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
│    Leaking: NO (AdManager↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
│    ↓ PathClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: NO (AdManager↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ Object[].[92]
├─ com.example.projects.utility.AdManager class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static AdManager.mInstance
│                       ~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.example.projects.utility.AdManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ AdManager.mAdLoader
│                ~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.AdLoader instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ AdLoader.zzacr
│               ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcwt instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzcwt.zzgpi
│            ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxj instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzcxj.zzgpz
│            ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxr instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzcxr.zzgqh
│            ~~~~~    
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbpi instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzbpi.zzfph
│            ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdod instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzdod.zzhfl
│            ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdtz instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzdtz.value
│            ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbph instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzbph.zzfpg
│            ~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
│                ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ Object[].[0]
│               ~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdul instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzdul.value
│            ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzccd instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzccd.zzfwg
│            ~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcde instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzcde.zzbnm
│            ~~~~~
├─ android.widget.FrameLayout instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    mContext instance of com.example.projects.ui.DynamicActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ FrameLayout.mContext
╰→ com.example.projects.ui.DynamicActivity instance
Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.projects.ui.DynamicActivity                                 
received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
```

To be more precise, how can or better said when do I destroy my unified native ad view when it is in a RecyclerView Viewholder. I don't mean the ad object itself, I mean the ad view from xml file.

Answer (score 0):

you should destroy the ad before the activity / fragment get destroyed
**in activity**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (nativeAd != null) {
            nativeAd.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**in fragment**:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (nativeAd != null) {
            nativeAd.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

Comment: Not working. I have the same issue. The leak still remains even if I remove the ad view from its parent. Don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

from official documentation:

> Ensure that all NativeAd references are destroyed in your activity's
> onDestroy() method.
>
> In your onNativeAdLoaded callback, make sure to destroy any existing
> native ads that will be dereferenced.
>
> Another key check is if the activity is destroyed and if so, call
> destroy() on the returned ad and return immediately:

```
final AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
        .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd ad) {
        // If this callback occurs after the activity is destroyed, you
        // must call destroy and return or you may get a memory leak.
        // Note `isDestroyed()` is a method on Activity.
        if (isDestroyed()) {
            ad.destroy();
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
}).build();
```